# Using WordPress API with Slim 3 and Twig Views

Tags: php, wordpress, slim, guzzle, wp-api

I'm trying to integrate a decoupled `wordpress/wp-api` to a Slim 3 framework with Twig views.

- Ideally I want to send all posts to `/posts` route rendered via Twig and
- Individual posts to `/post/hello-world` route

I'm having two issues for now:

1. I want to pass the response back (queried via guzzle) to a Twig view and I'm struggling with that.
2. The JSON response I'm getting back in the view is not an appropriate JSON response when I echo `$body`;

   ```
   // ROUTES
   $app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
   return $this->view->render($response, 'home.html');
   })->setName('home');

   $app->get('/posts/', function ($request, $response,array $args) {
       $client = new Client();
       $url ='/cms/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
       $res = $client->request('GET',$url,array(
                   'content-type' => 'application/json'
           ),array());
       $body = $res->getBody();
       // echo $body;
       return $this->view->render( $response,'posts.html',array('posts' => $body));
   })->setName('posts');
   ```

I would really like to keep using Twig with Slim instead of using Vue.js or Angular and build a SPA.